# System.Drawing on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, system.drawing

I am new at Xamarin, and need little help. I have libraries writen for windows and iOS that use System.Drawing (using monotouch.dll if understand well). 
Now i need to adapt those libraries to work on Android, is there an easy way to do it, or i must manualy change them to work with Android.Graphics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into Splat, a cross-platform geometry/color library built by Paul Betts.

https://github.com/paulcbetts/splat

Answer (score 0):

The only items from System.Drawing in iOS are:

> ```
>    Point
>    PointF
>    Rectangle
>    RectangleF
>    Size
>    SizeF
> ```

For Android all these are available (plus some others like Color) so if the code compiles for iOS you are fine with Android as well.